# Power query Date Format in VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, powerquery

I am working on a power query in VBA  in Excel including some Date Format.
For Load&Close, and I choose the sheet, everything works perfect with Date Format; however, when I run the vba code the date format can not be showed correctly (it shows 44185 instead of 12/20/2020) ... I suppose it comes from the VBA Code... anyone has any idea? Thanks a lot for your help !!
VBA Code :

```
 With Data.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & qry.Name _
        , Destination:=Data.Range("$B$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdDefault
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & qry.Name & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        
        
    End With
```

Comment: The numbers are valid date values. Just apply the date _format_ you prefer to the cells/range in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `NumberFormat` property:

```
.NumberFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! But i don't want to use this kind  way (i have to find the colomn to defind this preperty). What I don't understand that with the Out of box way (Load from Query) it shows well the date but not with VBA code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. You must set the format to see the date otherwise you will see it as the number of days that has passed since 1/1/1900. You can read more about this here: https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/

Comment: Hi, Sorry I just found out there is no way with what I want ....so you are right , I have to find the colomn and defind the property. Thanks again for all your helps !